# Random background images in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, image, wordpress, background

I am using WP 3.5.1, twenty twelve child theme and PHP 5.2 on my server.
I am trying to use a php script(that works on my other websites) in order to get random background-image but it's not working:

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(<?php include ("bg.php"); echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat fixed;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $bg = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg');
  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
?>
```

my php file is in the same folder as the jpg's.
Any ideas?

No errors. If I use  background: url(1.jpg); (instead of php) it works fine but obviously shows 1 image.

Comment: Do the images one to five `.jpg` exist?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, they are on the server on the same folder as the php file. No errors. If I use  background: url(1.jpg); it works fine but obviously shows 1 image.

Comment: Can you try with `$selectedBg = $bg[$i];`

Comment: As I said the code is fine and working on my other websites, but on this wordpress/blog it doesn't. Removing the quotes didn't help.

Comment: What does Firebug say in CSS background? Is it the correct image?

Comment: Is the php in your CSS file executing? You can check this by inspecting the file by viewing source. Many servers are not set up to parse php code in a .css file. You may need to make a style.php file or put the css in your header.php in some `<style>` tags.

Comment: The php is not found when viewing the websites source. I already tried adding it as a style on header.php but still not working. The server should support php code in css, it's the same server I host 2 other websites that this code works.

Answer (score 3):

Small solution:

We know that he have 5 images on the server:

```
'1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'
```

So quick tip:

```
<body style="background: url('pahttoimages/<?= rand(1, 5) ?>.jpg') no-repeat top center;">
```

Comment: Not working, I am sure it would work on my non-wordpress sites but when I use php on the background url it seems to ignore it.

Comment: It work's everyhere)) Try this one url(' <?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/youimagesfolder/<?= rand(1, 5) ?>.jpg')

Comment: Not working, it seems to ignore the php like with my other code. Seems like it's a server or theme issue, will do more research and post back.

Comment: also you can try <?php echo rand(1, 5); ?>

Answer (score 1):

i think the CSS file can't explain your PHP code
try `body {
    background: url(<?php echo '1.jpg'; ?>) no-repeat fixed;
}`

Comment: I edited my code on first post and added the "include". But it still doesn't work. I think echo is the issue, even if I add the jpg on echo it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your code is valid.

Except, you should really write the last line like:

```
$selectedBg = $bg[$i];
```

No need for quotes here.

---

I suspect this is what is causing the error:

> my php file is in the same folder as the jpg's. Any ideas?

The background-image needs to be relative to the template-file you are using, not the PHP-file. You script will only work if the images are located in the same folder as the template-slices.

In my WP-installation, I have a template located in `/wp-content/themes/mytemplate/` and template-graphics located in `/wp-content/themes/mytemplate/images/`. If I were to use your script, I would need to preappend `/images/` before all the backgrounds in your array.

---

By the way, you should consider installing Firebug on Firefox and inspect the source. Is the background-name parsed into the template? Does loading the image return a 404 not found-error? Is the location and path correct?

---

```
background-image: url(<?php include ("bg.php"); echo $selectedBg; ?>);
background-position: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: So, I have to add the images/php file on wp-content/theme/mytheme/... etc? Right now I have just uploaded the images and the php on the public_html folder of my server.

Comment: @zefs - It is almost impossible for me to track down what is wrong. You could try to add `/` in front of all the image-names to see if that works. I am not sure how WP is processing image-locations. You should look in Firebug under Net to see what it is trying to load.

Comment: Pathing isn't the problem here, if I use "1.jpg" instead of php it works fine. It's like php is not working when adding it on the background for that wordpress theme, but I can't seem to get why.

Comment: Ah, okey. Is the php-file located in the same folder as the template-file in which you are including it?

Comment: Yes, chrome inspector says "invalid property value" for the background: style.

Comment: @zefs - Try the simple expanded CSS I provided in my answer. I can't really see what is wrong with yours tho.

Comment: I think I know what is wrong, we are adding the background on the wrong body{}. I think it should be added on body.custom-background{} of the theme, but not sure where to find that. Will do some research and let you guys know.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
// bg.php
<?php

return array(
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg',
    '3.jpg'
);

// Wordpress CSS
<?php
$imageUrls = include('bg.php');
$imageUrl = $imageUrls[ array_rand($imageUrls) ];
?>
.someClass {
    background-image: url(<?php echo $imageUrl ?>);
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the question? This is just written another way. I can also reformat the code in 7,823,828,374,627,846 different ways, but it will still not solve the problem.

Comment: Written in a better and more readable way (without throwing global variables all over the place). At least he's sure PHP won't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url('<?php $a = array('darkred.jpg','red.gif','pink.png'); echo $a[array_rand($a)];?>');
```